# Django ORM with UUID fields using sqlite3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite

I have multiple models with the following structure:

```
class Element(models.Model):
    api_id = models.UUIDField(null=False, blank=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    ....

class Category(models.Model):
    api_id = models.UUIDField(null=False, blank=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    ....
```

...and so on.

Then, I can fetch objects from the `Element` table:

```
element = Element.objects.first()
element.api_id
UUID('8b278133-b8a2-4540-9dd0-129dd1394fcc')
Element.objects.filter(api_id='8b278133-b8a2-4540-9dd0-129dd1394fcc').count()
1
```

So far, so good. The error comes when I do the same on the `Category` table:

```
category = Category.objects.first()
category.api_id
UUID('f63b5052-fba1-4ad1-a8ec-673efc673f44')
Category.objects.filter(api_id='f63b5052-fba1-4ad1-a8ec-673efc673f44').count()
0
```

The same occurs if I explicity convert the string to UUID:

```
Category.objects.filter(api_id=uuid.UUID('f63b5052-fba1-4ad1-a8ec-673efc673f44')).count()
0
```

Both queries are converting the `api_id` to an integer:

```
str(Element.objects.filter(api_id='8b278133-b8a2-4540-9dd0-129dd1394fcc').query)
SELECT ... FROM "element" WHERE "element"."api_id" = 8b278133b8a245409dd0129dd1394fcc

str(Category.objects.filter(api_id='f63b5052-fba1-4ad1-a8ec-673efc673f44').query)
SELECT ... FROM "category" WHERE "category"."api_id" = f63b5052fba14ad1a8ec673efc673f44
```

Note that the `Element` query works as expected.

And in the database, both fields are created as `char (32)`:

```
CREATE TABLE "element" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "api_id" char(32) NOT NULL, ...)
CREATE TABLE "category" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "api_id" char(32) NOT NULL, ...)
```

So, if everything is equal for all the tables, why are the `Category` queries are not finding nothing by this `uuid` field?

I'm using Python 3.5, Django 2.0, and SQLite 3.
I tested with Postgres 9.5 and it works as expected. Only happens with SQLite3.